# Change value of mat-slider to default value on click of button

Tags: angular, mat-slider

```
<mat-slider thumbLabel min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0" >

<button type="button" (click)="Refresh()">Click Me!</button>

Refresh(){
// What should be written in this

}
```

Suppose I changed this slider and when I click on refresh button, I need to adjust the value again to zero

Can any one explain how to do it..

ThankYou....!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add value as `ngModel` to change it as needed

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mnycir?file=src/app/slider-overview-example.ts) is a stackblitz example

**ts**

```
value: number = 0

Refresh(){
  this.value = 0
}
```

**html**

```
<mat-slider thumbLabel min="0" max="100" step="1" [(ngModel)]="value" ></mat-slider>
<button type="button" (click)="Refresh()">Click Me!</button>
```